# UICollectionView inside UIViewController not allowing scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, collectionview

***Edit1: I am not using a storyboard everything has been added programmatically***
***Edit2: Updated code snippet***

## Hello, i've got the following issues with UICollectionView

- ***The CollectionView won't allow you to scroll no matter what you do.***
- ***Sometimes the cells even disappear complete leaving you with a white background CollectionView.***

## The problem occurs when you try to scroll up to view the cells that are not visible.

- *I've create a CollectionView which has different type of cells.*
- *The CollectionView is nested inside a ViewController below an ImageView.*
- *Constraints are added and they work just fine.*

### How do i make it scrollable?

**GIF representing the problem**

[image: GIF Video]

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.title = "Featured"
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    
    // Add UImage carousel
    let carousel: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let image = UIImage()
        
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
                    
        return imageView
    }()
    self.view.addSubview(carousel)
    carousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // Add CollectionView
    let featuredControllerLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    // Add CollectionViewController
    featuredControllerLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let featuredController = FeaturedCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: featuredControllerLayout)
    guard let featuredView = featuredController.collectionView else { return }
    
    self.view.addSubview(featuredView)
    featuredView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // Setup Constraints
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let guideSize = guide.layoutFrame.size
        
        carousel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        carousel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        carousel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        carousel.frame.size.height = guideSize.width/2
        carousel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: carousel.frame.size.height).isActive = true
        
        featuredView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        featuredView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        featuredView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: carousel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        featuredView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? This just looks like the data has run out. What is the green background from?

Comment: When you scroll up and lift your finger off the screen the collectionView pops back. "Recommended Items" is shown half way. The green background is an empty cell i've added.

Comment: It looks like you have conflicting constraints. Your `v:|view|` constraint will be conflicting with your safe area insets guide constraint. Remove one of them.

Comment: You should see a message telling you that these conflicts exist.

Comment: Neither getting message nor removing the code worked. I suspect it has something to do with the collectionViewLayout. I updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy what you are telling is you are not able to scroll up and see the entire collection view items ?

if that is the case then you have not accounted the height of tabbar controller so you can enable translucent for example I have a git repo I made you can check and let me know if you are stuck anywhere

https://github.com/dwivediashish00/socialApp

Comment: collectionView.bottomAnchor is set to tabBar.topAnchor so the collectionView height is correct i just cant get it to scroll without it bouncing back to top. I have trouble relating your code to mine although its similar. What is your code suggestion i should add?

Comment: yes you need not set bottom anchor to top of tabbar just adjust the content inset of the collection view for example try doing something like  collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0, right: 0) and try adding more section and items to confirm if its actually scrolling for just test purposes. you can just refer ViewController -> ViewDidLoad code for clarity

Comment: unfortunately it is not working by removing the anchor and adding contentInsets...

Comment: Sorry for late reply you need to set the bottom anchor of collection view to the self.view.bottomAnchor try this and lets get this working and let me know if this works or else will send you code.

Comment: Anchors are working fine. I guess it has something to do with the collectionView scrolling. Even though i set the things you told me to, it didn't work. I got to set the collectionView height smaller so it appears over the tabBar with visible space between them and still the scrolling is not working. It just bounces back when you try to scroll up. Here is a [GIF](https://media2.giphy.com/media/1hAWU2qiQmAFO60rlp/giphy.gif?cid=4bf119fc5c0f36aa2e56674c4d3f4969) visualising it all (the green background is an emptyCell for testing the scroll)

Comment: Hey can you give me some steps to replicate this issue so that i can work on a fix asap ?

Comment: Uploaded the project to [GitHub](https://github.com/achompolov/igra4kite-iOS).
File containing the collectionView is FeaturedViewController.swft

Comment: Heyy thanks !, I was able to make your collection view scroll so check out the PR will put another commit when I am able to make the scrolling work by using your cells. Mostly one of the reason your cells turning white is that you are trying to embed collection view controller inside the cells this is strange why don't you just create collectionView and embed in the cell ?

Comment: Well i need the horizontal collectionViews. Is there other way to do so? You managed getting it to work?

Comment: Thank you. The problem was i was giving the cells CGRect and returning the cells. With added function sizeForItemAt at just giving them CGSize it worker. Updating the question.

Comment: Thats great, 